# Excluding manifest from the final jar

Tags: java, gradle, jar, meta-inf

I'm trying to exclude the manifest file from the final jar artifact using gradle.

Weirdly I haven't found anything online and my attempts at it yielded no results.

My jar block currently:

```
jar {
    archivesBaseName = 'LRM2'
    
    exclude("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF")
}
```

Comment: May I ask why you want do to that?

Comment: The launcher for the project uses -cp to include it among other jars and where I'm deploying it there is a security thing that I cant change that has issues with downloading .mf files(which is weird because it doesnt care about the .class files)